# PL SQL replace string issue

Tags: plsql

Hi i am writing a procedure in PL SQL where i need to retrieve a string and replace some values in it.
My issue is that the replace statement doesn't not work if i pass variables in it.

```
tempPrewMonth      VARCHAR2(20);
tempMonth          VARCHAR2(20);
link               VARCHAR(400);


//First of all i stored values in the variables tempPrewMonth and  tempMonth

SELECT to_char((c.month-1),'09')
       INTO tempPrewMonth
       FROM dual;


SELECT to_char((c.month),'09')
        INTO tempMonth
        FROM dual;


//Replace the  "tempPrewMonth" in the "link" variable with "tempMonth" value (this part doesn't work. I don't get any error but the replacement doesn't work)


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select replace (:1,:2,:3)                
                    from dual' 
INTO link
USING link,tempPrewMonth,tempMonth ;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_char(...,'fm09')` instead of `to_char(...,'09')`.